# How to link/install CameraRoll , in react native

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, camera-roll

Every damn tutorial mentions about linking CameraRoll but doesn't explain how to link it, tried searching a lot but, couldnt find a proper guide. I know that CameraRoll is already present under node_modules but that folder doesn't contain any Xcode project file just source, can anybody please explain how that is supposed to be added ?

Answer (score 0):

Its part of the react-native api as in the docs so you don't need to link
Follow : https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/cameraroll.html#permissions

So you just do :

import React, { CameraRoll } from 'react-native'
Take a look at the example from the docs, it's quite complete.

To Ignore in docs :

On iOS, the CameraRoll API requires the RCTCameraRoll library to be linked. You can refer to Linking Libraries (iOS) to learn more.

To follow:
Permissions Section

Comment: Exactly that’s what my question is about how to link , because node modules folder doesn’t have Xcode project file so it’s not possible to add library project to Xcode

Comment: Yes you are right.So the thing here is, CameraRoll is Inbuilt api provided by react-native.You just have to follow the permissions sections from the official docs. there is no need to configure it via Xcode or any any third Party module.

In case you are wondering how it will work follow this link after adding the permissions in your Info.plist file.

https://snack.expo.io/BkhOYRPUZ

Comment: That isn’t true even though it’s inbuilt it needs to be linked because using it directly gives errors